# Angular schematics: is it possible to include a template file into another one

Tags: angular-schematics

When creating custom schematics with `@angular-devkit/schematics`, is their a way  to include a template file into another ?

I can't find documentation about this feature. I can't even find the template engine used.

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the source code i've finally created my own include function function. It render the template and returns the result. I then pass this function to the template files and call it.

I've created a git repository demo https://github.com/scallacs/schematics-demo.